# How to add point on Cubric Bezier Curve?

Tags: wpf, bezier

In photoshop we can create bezier curve with pen tool,when we editing the completed curve,we can add point on the curve, in blend  the same.
Now I have create a bezier path with wpf,how can I add point on it ,the special problem is I can't compute the control point of the new point. 
Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

what photoshop does is not "adding a control point", because that would raise the curve's order and change the curvature; instead, it splits the cubic curve into two cubic curves C1 and C2, with the endpoint of C1 and the startpoint of C2 are the same coordinate.

If WPF doesn't have curve splitting built into the API, then you might need to implement curve splitting yourself. It's pretty straight forward; for the DIY explanation, see http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting

The only challenge is to find the "t" value for the coordinate where you clicked, the simplest solution for that being to just generate the curve from t=0:1 in 1/100 or 1/1000 steps, and recording the x/y coordinate at each t value. That gives you a lookup table for instant lookup when you need to split the curve.

Comment: Now I have get the T and I split the curve to two ,But I can't Calculate the four new control points of the two new curves.
How can I get the four new control points ?

Comment: the splitting algorithm generates all the points you need for the two subcurves - http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting has a code listing that shows how you aggregate all the C1 (left) and C2 (right) curve points.